# if anidadados en SQL no funciona

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un problema en mi query ya que no me esta imprimiendo los mensajes en los if mas internos, no se que estoy haciendo mal, solo me imprime el valor del else mas externo(del if principal), la condicion principal es verdadera y se va siempre al else principal y me imprime 0

```html
IF EXISTS (SELECT top 1*
        FROM Rel_Contratos_Companias A
        INNER JOIN RelPlazaCompaniaEstadoCiudad B
        ON A.IdCompania = B.id_compania
        INNER JOIN DistribuidorEspecial  C
        ON B.Clv_Plaza = C.idDistribuidor
        INNER JOIN TipoDistribuidorEspecial D
        ON C.idTipoDistribuidorEspecial = D.idTipoDistribuidorEspecial
        Where a.Contrato =1000186 AND D.idTipoDistribuidorEspecial = 1)
        
        IF(@numeroPagos=1 AND @diasTranscurridos=0)
        
            SELECT 'No puede pagar' AS MesPagado;
        
        ELSE IF(@numeroPagos=0 AND @diasTranscurridos=0)
            
            SELECT 'Puede pagar' AS MesPagado;
            
                
    SELECT 1 AS DisOK;
    
ELSE

    SELECT 0 AS DisOK;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código no se ejecuta como tal. Le faltaría `BEGIN...END` para que no marque error en el `ELSE`.

Agregando eso, habría que ver si tienen valor las variables que mencionas y si es un valor correcto. Por ejemplo, con este código que corre en cualquier instancia puedo ver que si no le asigno valor a las variables, no regresa el primer resultado. Pero si descomento la asignación de valores, entonces sí lo hace.

```
DECLARE @numeroPagos int,
        @diasTranscurridos int

--SELECT @numeroPagos = 1,
--       @diasTranscurridos = 0;

IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM sys.objects)
BEGIN
    
        IF(@numeroPagos=1 AND @diasTranscurridos=0)
    
            SELECT 'No puede pagar' AS MesPagado;
    
        ELSE IF(@numeroPagos=0 AND @diasTranscurridos=0)
        
            SELECT 'Puede pagar' AS MesPagado;
        
            
    SELECT 1 AS DisOK;
END    
ELSE

    SELECT 0 AS DisOK;
```